# Jquery time picker, .selector is not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have used time picker code from the 
http://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Easy-Time-Selector-with-jQuery-jQuery-UI-timeselect.html

```html
    
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/flick/jquery-ui.min.css" /> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/date-en-US.js">&lt;/script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.ui.timeselect.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $('#<%=txtTimePicker.ClientID%>').timeselect({ 
             autocompleteSettings: 
                 { 
                    autoFocus: true 
                    }
         }
                );
     });
<script>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtTimePicker" runat="server" />
```

I am getting the following error:
0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'timeselect'

Comment: Is `&lt;/script>` a typo?

Comment: sorry.. I made mistake when posting..

Answer (score 0):

this line isn't going to work

```
$('#<%=txtTimePicker.ClientID%>').timeselect({
```

Should probably be

```
$('#txtTimePicker').timeselect({
```

Comment: Did you mean `$('#txtTimePicker')`?

Comment: I changed it.. but still not working...getting same error.

Comment: if you browse the source and click the link to timeselect.js, does the js file load?

Comment: Its loaded.. Now I am getting this error from the timeselect.js.. 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'autocomplete'

Answer (score 0):

try this script .Hope this will help you

```
<!-- this should go after your </body> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/jquery.datetimepicker.css"/ >
<script src="/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>
```

add the following script on document.ready event

```
jQuery('#txtTimePicker').datetimepicker({
  datepicker:false,
  format:'H:i'
});
```

Comment: Yes. I tried.. I am getting this error from datetimepicker.js.       0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'off'

Comment: Please ensure that you kept the script until **DOM** finishes loading. Then you can apply your scripts. Since, in your master page, you are using the script at the bottom, since the parser uses **top down** approach, it executes the script, after the body is completed loading.

Comment: I think the problem araised because of the second inclusion of jquery.you have included the jquery file twice.second inclusion will overwrite the first one.please check that also

Comment: Now I tried this way. In the master page code behind I have registered this script, Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("jQueryDateTime", VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Scripts/jquery.datetimepicker.js"));

Comment: In the Masterpage.master <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Stylesheets/jquery.datetimepicker.css"/> In the timepicker.ascx user control,  <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $('#txtTimePicker').datetimepicker({
             datepicker: false,
             format: 'H:i'
         });
     });
    </script>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtTimePicker" runat="server" /> Here, I am getting the above error,